# News Feed search API for facebook not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=facebook`
I was trying to use the above as search on news feed as there is no option for the news feed search here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search
 But as if we log into facebook, we are able to search at least from our news feed.
Is there any way/undocumented option for fetching search results ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is a very localized question about what FB endpoint to use, which is not a programming question per se.

Comment: @J0e3gan I have updated the question, need not to

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to search for posts anymore. The only way to get access to posts is by authorizing a user with `user_posts`. Of course this will only get you access to the posts of the authorized user - and the posts of his friends on his wall.